# Exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' was thrown ? in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i wanna use simple database in Xamarin Forms. So i used this code;

public partial class DBExample : ContentPage

```
{
    string _dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),"myDB.db3");
    public DBExample ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
    private async void InsertButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SQLiteConnection db=null;
        try
        {
            db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           await DisplayAlert(null, ex.Message, "OK");
        }

        db.CreateTable<Users>();
        var maxPk = db.Table<Users>().OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        Users users = new Users()
        {

            Id = (maxPk == null ? 1 : maxPk.Id + 1),
            Name = userName.Text
        };
        db.Insert(users);
        await DisplayAlert(null,userName.Text + "saved","OK");
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }

}
```

and i have problem. You can see it in Headtitle.

"Exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' was thrown"

im waiting your support. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: So which exception is it `KeyNotFoundException` or `OutOfMemoryException`'?

Comment: sorry, i changed headtitle. It was wrong. My problem is KeyNotFoundException.

Comment: I am not familiar with modern C#, but it looks like your code does not exit if SQLiteConnection(_dbPath); throws an exception.
It will show a dialog and continue trying to operate on a null db object.

Comment: i created a Interface for connection. It Solved. Thanks for answering